# "Cannot Save Credit Memo" error in Magento

Tags: magento

here's what I found out on the system.log

2015-02-19T19:35:03+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: URI  in /home/neoflam/public_html/shop/app/design/frontend/default/shopper/template/page/html/head.phtml on line 39

Comment: This isn't really a question. Please explain what your question is and give us some background. Explain it well enough that it's possible that someone who had never heard of magneto before (like me) might still be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that magento is trying to create a credit memo with the same id number as one that has already been created. **disclaimer** **backup your database first, editing the database directly is dangerous**.  you could try logging into php myadmin find the sales_flat_creditmemo table and then the incriment_id column.  change the number of the last record to one that hasn't been used.(just use next number) e.g.: if the number is 50565, change it to 50566.  You may consider an extension that allows you control over memo, shipping and order numbers. we use "custom_order_number" by Amasty and it works well. it allows you control over the numbers for order, shipping, memo etc.